# Wordpress backend design

Tags: wordpress, navigation, admin

I have to build an "admin only" page where an admin user can input 3 objects - a person's "name", "description" and a photo. this way they can add/edit/delete people from the website.

I have tried adding "add_menu_page()" to the admin navigation menu and that worked, but I'm kind of lost as to what to do next, or even if I'm on the right track.

I'm assuming I will load the people into the WP database and query the database when i need to display each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track. Just create a form for the admin where he/she can enter the name, description and photo of a person.

You should make another page using the same method i.e. `add_menu_page()` and load your WP DB there and provide the option to the admin to delete, edit or add from there.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a form using WP Forms but I do not know how to get it to display on my new menu page. Currently the new menu page has only some html that I echo'd from the functions.php file in the theme. Either I echo the entire form or I use the WP Form somehow.